# Google calendar api (Calendar usage limits exceeded)

Tags: php, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am using Google Calendar Api in my php project, and I every day get "Calendar usage limits exceeded" message when I doing insert query, but delete and list methods work fine․ It is my insert function. who can help me?

```
function insertEvent($start, $end, $cId, $namePhoneClient,$myEmail,$trainerMail){

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => $namePhoneClient,
    'start' => array(
      'dateTime' => $start,
      'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
    ),
    'end' => array(
      'dateTime' => $end,
      'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
    ),
    'recurrence' => array(
      'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1'
    ),
    'attendees' => array(
      array('email' => $myEmail),
      array('email' => $trainerMail),
    ),
));

$calendarId = $cId;
$event_inserted = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

return $event_inserted; 
}
```

Comment: please post the exact message

Comment: How many inserts do you run in one day? I think somewhere google publishes the usage limits, so you can check if your normal execution would exceed it.

Comment: [{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"quotaExceeded","message":"Calendar usage limits exceeded."}]

Comment: today I do 2500 query

Comment: Good question.
I want to become a friend with you and have something to discuss with you.
My personal email is zangwei.mk@outlook.com, could you let me know your contact info?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the API usage limits [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/pricing) and [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en).

They are as follows:

- 1,000,000 total queries per day
- 100,000 created events in a short period of time
- 60 calendars created in a short period of time
- 10,000 invites to external guests in a short period of time
- 2,000 emails sent through 'Email guests' feature in a short period of time
- 750 calendar shares in a short period of time

I suggest that you insert fewer events.

Comment: I know this and there is no overshoot in the console

Comment: Calendar usage limits exceeded is normally related to limits on google calendar itself and not related to the Google calendar api.   If you feel this answer is inaccurate even though as you say it comes directly from the documentation.  I dont think that google would not have inaccurate information in their documentation.. Please consider posting your own answer with what you consider to be accurate information,  I would love to see it.