# Getting "Calendar usage limits exceeded" on creating google calendar events

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-apis-explorer

**What I am trying to achieve:** - I am trying to create an application through which I can create multiple calendar events having 4 attendees each at a particular time. For eg: I should be able to send different meet links to different groups but same meet link to the members of that group for a particular time.

**For eg:** 
 Group 1 has 4 members (m1,m2,m3,m4)
Group 2 has 4 members (m5,m6,m7,m8) 
I should be able to generate two calendar events one for each group having respective members in attendees.
When event is created user should get the notification of the event.

**Note:** Attendees are external to my domain.

**Tech Stack -** using googleapis npm package and application is in node.js

**Problem -** I am creating multiple events but after creating only 4 to 5 events, I start receiving the error "Calendar usage limits exceeded".

**Snippet of my code**

```
module.exports = {
  scheduleHangoutMeeting: (createLinkObj) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(CREDENTIAL_PATH, async (err, content) => {
        if (err) resolve(err);
        try {
          let auth = await authorize(JSON.parse(content));
          let calendarEvent = await createCalendarEvents(auth, createLinkObj);
          resolve(calendarEvent);
        }
        catch (err) {
          resolve(err);
        }
      });
    });
  } 
};
```

```
let createCalendarEvents = (auth, meetingObj) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    
    let createEvent = {
      summary: 'Testing Calendar Api',
      description: 'Please ignore this events is for testing purpose',
      start: {
        dateTime: meetingObj.start_time,
        timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: meetingObj.end_time,
        timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
      },
      attendees: meetingObj.attendees,
      reminders: {
        useDefault: false,
        overrides: [
          { method: 'email', minutes: 24 * 60 },
          { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 },
        ],
      },
      conferenceData: {
        createRequest: {
          requestId: 'someRandomKey',
        },
      },
      guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: false
    };

    try {
      let calendarEvent = await calendar.events.insert(
        {
          auth: auth,
          calendarId: 'primary',
          resource: createEvent,
          sendNotifications: true,
          conferenceDataVersion: 1
        }
      );
      resolve(calendarEvent.data);
    } 
    catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

I have gone through various questions on stackoverflow, which talks about the quotas but my number of events are much less and within the quotas. You can refer to the below screenshot for the number of queries. On 19th feb, there were only 6 queries after which we started getting the error and if we count the total number of queries sent to google till date, it would be around 190. Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong.

**Error Message**

> code: 403,   errors: [
> {
> domain: 'usageLimits',
> reason: 'quotaExceeded',
> message: 'Calendar usage limits exceeded.'
> }   ]

**Quota Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Team, this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247565/google-calendar-api-calendar-usage-limits-exceeded) is similar to mine. But it doesn't resolve my question as it states only the conditions where this situation arises, but it doesn't state if any haven't crossed that limit, why then he is receiving that error. In that question user did 2500 query per day but I created only around 60 events and started getting the error.  As such would request you to please reopen this question, so that I can get a direction towards resolving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Calendar usage limits exceeded—Results from an API call.

[image]

#### To avoid exceeding Calendar limits, follow these guidelines:

#### DON'T...

1. Create too many events

If you create more than 100,000 events in calendar during a short period, you might lose calendar edit ability for a few hours.
It might take several months until this limit type is fully replenished.

2. Create too many calendars

If you create more than 60 new calendars in a short period, your calendar might go into read-only mode for several hours.
It might take several hours until this limit type is fully replenished.

3. Send too many invitations to external guests

To prevent spamming, Google Calendar limits the number of invitations a user sends to external guests. If a user sends 10,000 invites in a short period, the user’s calendar might go into read-only mode.
Inviting Google Workspace users in your primary or secondary domain will not consume this limit type. Users in your domain that are not on Google Workspace systems are considered external.
It might take several days until this limit type is fully replenished.

4. Email too many guests via Google Calendar events

To prevent spamming, Google Calendar limits the number of emails a user can send to external guests with the ‘Email Guests’ feature.
Using the ‘email guests’ feature with Google Workspace users in your primary or secondary domain does not consume this limit type.
This limit replenishes gradually within 24 hours.

5. Share calendars with too many users

If you share calendars with many users in a short period, you might lose the ability to share calendars for a few hours.
It might take several hours until this limit type is fully replenished.

#### Reference:

See Google support page reference link to avoid Calendar use limits, and follow the guidelines(the same with what I indicated above) on this page to avoid exceeding limits: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en

Comment: Thank you Monique for the details. I have already gone through the documentation. But the problem is I believe, I haven't crossed any limits mentioned in the documentatio,n then also I am getting the error. Is there a way to know which limit I have crossed, if any.

Comment: I have added the latest quotas screenshot @Monique G. Here you can see that the number of queries sent on 19th Feb. 2021 is only 6 which is way below the permissible limits as mentioned in the google support docs then also I am getting the error. Can you please suggest what could be the possible issue.